# Querying in Rails with multiple hash conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm referring to hash conditions as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions). Could you use multiple types of hash conditions? Like equality and subset? I tried it, and it's giving me a syntax error:

```
@colleges = College.where(category: "#{@university_type}" and "us_news_ranking < #{@rank_low}").first
```

Is it possible to do this, or is my code just wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this, or is my code just wrong?

Your code is just wrong. `and` isn't involved in this; if you want several conditions, supply several several keys/values to `where`. In this case, you need two `where` calls - one for the equality condition, and one for the less-than condition.

You also should *never* interpolate values directly into your string. Use placeholders so ActiveRecord can escape them and prevent SQL injection.

```
@colleges = College.where(category: @university_type).where("us_news_ranking < ?", @rank_low).first
```

Comment: I'm getting a NoMethodError because the object is nil. For the first where statement, `@university_type` should  be an array and I want it to test to see if `category` is in that array. Is my code doing that?

Comment: Examine the SQL it outputs in your logs. Yes, if it's an array, it will be building a `where category in (....)` condition.

Comment: That code is incorrect in many aspects. `@university_type` is a bad variable name, if it is Array. It should be plural! Also, `category` and `type` are not the same things. It is not beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine both conditions:

```
@colleges = College.where("category = ? AND us_news_ranking < ?", 
              @university_type, 
              @rank_low).first
```

Also, sometimes preffer to use hash variables:

```
@colleges = College.where("category = :type AND us_news_ranking < :rank",
              type: @university_type, 
              rank: @rank_low).first
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use `"#{@university_type}"`, and it's a very bad idea to ever interpolate a value directly into a string.